# How to show message layout only to sender and receiver instead of everyone, in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: kotlin, adapter, messaging, firebaseui

When I send a message to a specific person, every user receives an empty layout (without the message).
How do I show the layout only to the recipient instead of every user? i'm using a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

```
 override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
                val model: ModelChat = getItem(position)

                    if (model.sender == firebaseUser!!.uid ) {
                        return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT
                    }
                    
                    else {
                        return MSG_TYPE_LEFT
                    }
            }
```

Anytime I text anyone, all the other existing users receive an empty message like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihGbX.png)

I'm able to control which users see that actual text itself in my bindview...using this:

```
 if (receiver == firebaseUser!!.uid && sender == visitorsUid ||
                                    receiver == visitorsUid && sender == firebaseUser!!.uid) {

                                myHolderChats.textmessageTv.setText(message)
```

but don't know how to do the same for the layouts...

Comment: Are you talking about a group chat or a separately receives an empty layout?

Comment: heyy thank you! but I resolved this and forgot to update